# Group the Files with certain value in the path - C#

Tags: c#, performance, linq, file, directory-structure

I am creating a windows application (C#) to structure some files in folder.
My Folder structure is like

C:/Data/A/A1/d5/data/abc.xml

C:/Data/A/A1/cf/p3.xml

C:/Data/A/A2/p1/p2.xml

C:/Data/A/A2/m1/m2/cdf.xml

C:/Data/A/A3/c1/e1/Data/abc.xml

C:/Data/A/A3/ABC/cdf.xml

```
string path = "C:/Data/";

DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(Path);

FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

I expect to get A1, A2, A3 Folders.

My intention is to create a new folder under A1, A2, A3 and move all the XML there.
How can i get a certain folder name after a pattern in the path.
I have more than thousand xml files in files array. What is the efficient way to process this?

Comment: So what does or doesn't this do?

Comment: Are there only three of them? If so then why not just process them respectively?

Comment: There will be more folders.

Comment: Does the actual case matches the pattern `C:/Data/A/A<a number>`?

Comment: it matches with patterrn

Comment: Also consider using the [BackgroundWorker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker?view=netframework-4.8) to do the lengthy files moving routine in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of how many time it needs to loop or perhaps check if the directory exists or not

```
string path = "C:/Data/A/A";
for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
{
    var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles($"{path}{i}", "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    Directory.CreateDirectory($"{path}{i}/new-folder/");
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        File.Move(file, $"{path}{i}/new-folder/{Path.GetFileName(file)}");
    }
}
```